# Paste terms in URL

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am trying to find a way to create a simple dynamic URL, that gets its information from boxes where people enter something.

I got a google search machine and want to refer to it, so basically I wanted two boxes:
One for choosing which directory to search in (the google machine has different directories in its index I want people to be able to choose from those)
and the other for the search term they are looking for.

The URL looks like that:
http://searchengine.xx/search?q=SEARCHTERM&site=DIRECTORY&btnG=Suchen&entqr=0&ud=1&sort=date%3AD%3AL%3Ad1&output=xml_no_dtd&oe=UTF-8&ie=UTF-8

I tried it with PHP like that:

```
<?php
$directory = $_GET['searchterm'];

echo "http://searchengine.xx/search?q=".$searchterm."&site=directory&btnG=Suchen&  entqr=0&ud=1&sort=date%3AD%3AL%3Ad1&output=xml_no_dtd&oe=UTF-8&ie=UTF-8'>URL</a>
?>
```

This doesnt seem to work well and I wondered if this was possible in any other way (simple HTML, JavaScript maybe?)

Comment: You're missing `<a href='` from the start of your echo, is that the issue? What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work well"?

Comment: Its not that, its the output link being incorrect.
Is there any other way than PHP?

Comment: How is it incorrect? Post an example

Comment: uhm, there is another problem now. Obviously PHP doesn't work properly, if I call the page there is just ?> . 
But I got an Apache with PHP and all stuff, WordPress is running correctly there. Do I have to consider anything ?

Comment: You need to fix your echo statement. You haven't closed the double quotes, and it should end with a semicolon.

Comment: I'm stuck, I dunno how to fix it. Sometimes just nothing appears, or it's just the ?>

Answer (score 0):

try to mix php and htaccess...

Comment: the output link isnt correct, i dont know why. I am not really familiar with any of those web scripting languages, any suggestions how to solve it other way than with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//get the text form the text box and put it in a variable eg.($text) 
$url = 'index.php?searchterms=$text';
header("Location: $url"); 
?>
```

I think that something like this might work.

Get the text from the text box, then put the text onto a variable (i've used $text to exemplify).
Put the url that you want in a variable (i've used $url to exemplify), but in the end of the url put the text variable the way i did it.
Finally, use the header function to redirect to the url that you want.

Hope i helped

Comment: Looks great, I'll try as soon as I can. 
Unfortunately I seem to have problems with php itself.
The only output is ?> if I call the page, what am I doing wrong? WordPress is running flawless on my Webserver?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with the PHP code in your question. $searchterm is never set and the echo statement is never ended. Try this instead:

```
<?php
    $searchterm = $_GET['searchterm'];
    $searchterm = strip_tags($searchterm);
    echo "<a href='http://searchengine.xx/search?q=".$searchterm."&site=directory&btnG=Suchen&entqr=0&ud=1&sort=date%3AD%3AL%3Ad1&output=xml_no_dtd&oe=UTF-8&ie=UTF-8'>URL</a>";
?>
```

The [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) will ensure `"` and `'` are removed so it doesn't break your link.